# no Ubuntu software in unity 8

Tags: software-installation, mir, unity8

In Unity 8 (Ubuntu 16.10) I am unable to locate any apps. I have Ubuntu software in Unity (default), but I don't see it in Unity 8.

output of `gnome-software`:

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect: not accepted by server
[2016-12-13 17:52:38.886235] <ERROR> MirConnectionAPI: Caught exception at client library boundary (in release): /build/mir-SAnMsN/mir-0.24.0+16.10.20160815.3/src/client/rpc/stream_socket_transport.cpp(168): Throw in function virtual void mir::client::rpc::StreamSocketTransport::send_message(const std::vector<unsigned char>&, const std::vector<mir::Fd>&)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<mir::socket_disconnected_error> >
std::exception::what: Failed to send message to server: Broken pipe
32, "Broken pipe"
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-software:8193): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: i want to install apps.Even in the starting there was no ubuntu software store. i install apps using libertime.but it is not good.

Comment: how to install ubuntu software store in unity 8

Comment: Maybe it's just not listed in the dash for some reason. Could please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and try to run `gnome-software` (new Software Center for Ubuntu Yakkety) and `software-center` (deprecated in Yakkety) and report what happens? If you encounter any warning or error messages please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu.

Comment: **output of gnome-software** added in question